# Hyperledger composer calling external REST API

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am a developer with hyperledger composer. I try to use [Calling an HTTP or REST API from Transaction Processor Functions](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/call-out) with method POST and request body but I have error status code 500. I want to use method POST with request body to my server.

My code:

```
async function testStocks(transaction) {

    const participant = getCurrentParticipant();
    const json = '{"name:tester"}';//my request body

    await request.post({ uri: 'http://www...', json });

    // Update the current participant in the participant registry.
    const participantRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.example.Trader');
    await participantRegistry.update(participant);

}
```

My error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "Error trying invoke business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.\nResponse from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: StatusCodeError: 400 - undefined",
    "stack": "Error: Error trying invoke business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.\nResponse from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: StatusCodeError: 400 - undefined\n    at _initializeChannel.then.then.then.then.catch (/home/pc/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:965:34)\n    at <anonymous>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`participant` variable is undefined in `await participantRegistry.update(participant);`.

You are missing code from the example @ https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/call-out.

```
// Get the current participant, and update their stock and balance.
const participant = getCurrentParticipant();
// update participant here...  <<--------------------

// Update the current participant in the participant registry.
const participantRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.example.Trader');
await participantRegistry.update(participant);
```

Comment: Ooh, I see you have actually defined that above. My bad.

Comment: Now, It is work fine but I have error with CORS. Can you help me brrother?. I have use **https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/** but it work only with browser. My Error: `The response had HTTP status code 405. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled`.

Comment: To solve the CORS, I actually changed the source-code and added CORS header.